# UIPickerView only showing two gray lines

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

this is my first time on stackoverflow, and I'm very new to programming so forgive me if this is a bad question or something. Anyway, I tried to make a UIPickerView and the program runs successfully, but only two horizontal gray lines show up. I'll include some code and an image. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
let UIPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    
    UIPicker.delegate = self as? UIPickerViewDelegate
    UIPicker.dataSource = self as? UIPickerViewDataSource
    self.view.addSubview(UIPicker)
    UIPicker.center = self.view.center
    
    class LanguageNativeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
        
        let dataArray = ["English", "Spanish", "French", "German", "Italian", "Portuguese", "Russian", "Japanese"]
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
           return 1
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
           return dataArray.count
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
           let row = dataArray[row]
           return row
        }
```

[Image of app running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S3DK.jpg)

Comment: Are your three delegate methods ever called? Your code snippet looks correct but in your screenshot LanguageNativeViewController is neither a UIPickerViewDelegate or UIPickerViewDataSource

Comment: @WongWray Thank you so much--I fixed this and it worked. As a beginner struggling to figure this out I can't thank you enough

Comment: Glad it worked out -- happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference... when asking a question here, it's a good idea to post the actual code you're working on.

Since we have no idea where you are placing your code, give this a try:

```
class LanguageNativeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    let dataArray = ["English", "Spanish", "French", "German", "Italian", "Portuguese", "Russian", "Japanese"]

    let UIPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIPicker.delegate = self
        UIPicker.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(UIPicker)
        UIPicker.center = self.view.center
        
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let row = dataArray[row]
        return row
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

As a side note, use lower-case for variables and properties:

```
let uiPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
```

Comment: Will do. Thanks so much for helping